# Related entities in separate reducers in ngrx

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm developing my first ngrx app in angular and have a problem with related entities. I have two reducers, one called Page and on called Section. Down below is a simplified version of the structure. The section object has a pages array with pageIds which points to the pages in the page reducer.

```
// section.reducer.ts
sections: {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Section 1',
        pages: [1,2,3]
    }
}

// page.reducer.ts
pages: {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Page 1'
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Page 2'
    }
    3: {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Page 3'
    }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is when I want to add a new Page and add it to a Section. My first thought was to dispatch an AddPage action and handle it in both reducers. The problem then is that the Page object is created in the page reducer so the sections reducer doesn't know about it. I must at least have the pageId in the section reducer. I then thought that I could dispatch a AddPageSuccess with the newly created page so that the section reducer can handle it. The problem with that approach is that there is no reference to the store in the reducer so I can't dispatch any actions. I therefore tried adding it like an @effect. That will probably work but I'm not sure if it is the "correct" way to it. My impression is that effects should be used for async data, like rest calls. In this case everything is sync but have actions dependent on each other. Is @effects a "valid" way to achieve this scenario where actions are dependent on each other or is that kind of design wrong.

An alternative would be to have all state in the same reducer but that reducer would be massive since there will be a lot of logic for each part.

Answer (score 0):

Effects are for side effects, what you are thinking about effects solution is perfectly valid in my opinion. You are adding Page , but Section should also be aware of that. This is definitely a side effect right ? so, effects is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

@Effects are for actions with side effects. You've mentioned pure actions so far, (these have no side effects), so these should be handled by reducers.

You should have two actions, one for each reducer:

```
ADD_SECTION_PAGE
ADD_PAGE
```

When you want to add a page and add it to the section, dispatch two messages from the store:

```
onAddPage() {
    this.store.dispatch(new AddSectionPageAction({sectionId:1, page:4 }));
    this.store.dispatch(new AddPageAction({ id:4, title: 'Some Page Title' }));
}
```

The SectionReducer would find the section based on sectionId, and add the new page to the pages array.

The PageReducer would add the page to the PageState.

The calculation of the ID can either occur in your reducer:

```
newId = Object.keys(pagesState).length > 0 
  ? Object.keys(pagesState).sort().reverse()[0] + 1 : 1;
```

Or, if you add your page via  a web API call, add the page via an @effect, and pass the id to the ADD_PAGE action.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your suggestion. What I want to do is to add a new Page and at the same time add it to one of the Sections pages array, not adding a new Section. Since the Page doesn't have an ID when the ADD_PAGE action is dispatch, the sections reducer can't add i to one of the sections pages array. This means that I must first add the Page, wait for it to finish so it have an ID and then add it to the sections array. When I write this now it sounds like a side effect.

Comment: I see, I understand now. I still don't think its a side effect.

Comment: Ok, saw your edited response now, With that approach I need to know the ID for the new Page already in the component that dispatches the action. That feels like business logic and shouldn't that be in a reducer? For this implementation I think I'm safe with this approach since I'm using GUIDs but if I would have a number as id it would need to be unique and the logic for finding a unique id  should't be in the component that dispatches the action?

Comment: You are right. I would pass 0 for the id in the action, and have your reducer calculate the unique ID

Comment: But then we are back at my original question... The section reducer must have and ID on the new Page for it to be able to add it to a Sections pages array. This means that the ADD_PAGE action must finish first so that the Page has an ID and then add it to a section

Comment: Depends how you look at it. Adding a page to a section depends on the state in order to figure out what Id it needs. The reducers are passed the latest state - this makes it an ideal place to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146927/discussion-between-abris-and-pixelbits).

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://medium.com/@viestursv/how-to-get-store-state-in-ngrx-effect-fab9e9c8f087

You can have access to the state in the Effect class. See the related code below. Selector is a way to make slices of the state, and you will have to dispatch state with related data in the reducer to make update the state.

```

```js
@Effect() specialEffect$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(ADD_LINE)
    .withLatestFrom([
      this.store$.select(state => state.lines), 
      this.store$.select(state => state.pages])
    .map(([action: Action, linesOrPages: Lines|Pages]) => {
      // Do something ...
    });
```